# Встроить код смещения изображения в код смены картинки-ссылки на другую

Tags: css

Можно ли это:

```
.bgbutton{
    background-image: url("lglogo2.png");
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
.bgbutton:active{
    background-position: 0px 1px;
}
```

Встроить в это или как нибудь совместить?:

```
a.rollover {
    background:  url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 176px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding: 0px;
   }
   a.rollover:hover {
    background: url('lglogo2.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Если можно то как? И как это будет выглядеть в html?

Answer (score 1):

[Почитайте про css-свойство `background`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background):

```
background: [background-attachment || background-color || background-image 
  || background-position || background-repeat] | inherit
```

То-есть, оно включает в себя другие css-свойства, в том числе и `background-position`. В вашем коде для `a.rollover:hover` собраны свойства `background-image`, `background-position` и `background-repeat`. Соотвтественно вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
a.rollover:hover {
    background: url('lglogo2.png') 0 1px no-repeat;
}
```

для достижения желаемого эффекта.

**UPD.**

[Псевдо-класс `:active`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/active)

```
a.rollover:active {
    background: url('lglogo2.png') 0 1px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: смещение идет при наведении, а нужно при нажатии

Comment: Вы наверняка что-то напутали в css. Проверьте внимательно.

Comment: в нажатом и не нажатом виде все отображается корректно! сдвиг происходит отлично! Проблема в том что у меня все ссылки выделяются цветом при наведении на них курсора и эта картинка-ссылка тоже при наведении окрашивается этим цветом! Как это можно исправить?

Comment: например сделайте разные классы для **всех** ссылок и для этой картинки-ссылки и напишите для каждого из этих классов свои правила.

Comment: можете привести примеры классов для картинки-ссылки, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите небольшой javascript для этого случая, там есть и необходимые события мыши.
Собственно для такой ситуации - решение единственное.
<обрашение к объекту>.style.<имя свойства> = <значение>

соответественно задайте

```
<button class="bgbutton" onclick="func(this)"></button>
```

а для javascript:

```
function func(a) {
   a.style.backgroundPosition = "0 1px"
}
```

Как то так или около того, в сущности зависит от того как использовать. К сожалению не все свойства CSS есть в возможностях JS (CSS3 - спорный момент), но почти все.

Comment: Первая  строка делает из картинки-ссылки кнопку а  вторая, я не разобрался как её применить а если разобрался то эффекта нажатия не получилось.